# Plotting time-complexity vs actual run time

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

To my understanding, the time-complexity of an algorithm is a measure of its actual run time. For instance, an algorithm with a worst-case time-complexity $T(N)=$(constant)$\times N^2+$(lower order terms) has time-complexity $O(N^2)$ and, thus, has a run-time that increases at most quadratically with the size of its input when the input is significantly large.

I want to compare the time-complexity of the algorithm with its actual run-time by plotting each function on the same graph. How should I compare the actual run-time of an algorithm to its time-complexity in a graph if the x-axis is $N$? Should I plot both $T(N)$ and the actual run-time or $N^2$ and the actual run-time? This is for an academic paper, and I'm looking for what is usually done in literature. If papers in the field don't typically compare time complexity with actual run-time in this manner, how do they?